# Error trying to decode a Token using jwt-decode

Tags: react-native, mobile, expo

I am trying to establish communication between two projects. In one project, I have created an API called voll-api-nodejs, and the other project voll-mobile is the one consuming data from this API.

In the voll-api-nodejs project, I have the following code to generate the token signature:

```
const token = jwt.sign({ id, role }, process.env.SECRET, {
  expiresIn: 86400
}); // expires in 24 hours

res.status(200).json({
  auth: true,
  token
});
```

In my voll-mobile project, I am using the following code to consume data from my API and extract the token:

```
import { jwtDecode } from "jwt-decode";

const result = await api.post("/auth/login", {
  email,
  password,
});

const token = result.data.token;
const decodedToken = jwtDecode(token);
const myId = decodedToken.id;
```

The error occurs when using jwtDecode to decode the token. The error log is as follows: "Error decoding token: [InvalidTokenError: Invalid token specified: invalid base64 for part #2 (Property 'atob' doesn't exist)]"

Note: I used the website https://jwt.io/ to verify the authenticity of the token, and it is valid. I'll leave the token below if anyone wants to verify it as well:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjI1NzlkMTVmLWY0ZjEtNGEwOS04MGRjLTk3OTdiZmZmMzg4NyIsInJvbGUiOiJQQUNJRU5URSIsImlhdCI6MTcwMjY3MzM1MiwiZXhwIjoxNzAyNzU5NzUyfQ.Oz7iBmkfPCVDr0s-JlzGjyvpZIPvJBYsrjqOT0tJQ3w
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per `jwt-decode` [README.md](https://github.com/auth0/jwt-decode/blob/main/README.md#polyfilling-atob):

> This library relies on `atob()`, which is a global function available
> on all modern browsers as well as every supported node environment.
>
> In order to use `jwt-decode` in an environment that has no access to
> `atob()` (e.g. React Native), ensure to provide the corresponding
> polyfill in your application by using `core-js/stable/atob`:
>
> ```
> import "core-js/stable/atob";
> ```
>
> Alternatively, you can also use `base-64` and polyfill `global.atob`
> yourself:
>
> ```
> import { decode } from "base-64";
> global.atob = decode;
> ```

Comment: It worked! I'm not sure why the `atob()` was not available in my environment, but your snippet worked marvelously. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your input is containing `.` and `-`, which is making it impossible to decode. These items appear to be some separators, so you will need to `split` by them and decode them separately. This is a way that works syntactically, but it is up to you to decide whether it makes sense for your JWT.

```js
let raw = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjI1NzlkMTVmLWY0ZjEtNGEwOS04MGRjLTk3OTdiZmZmMzg4NyIsInJvbGUiOiJQQUNJRU5URSIsImlhdCI6MTcwMjY3MzM1MiwiZXhwIjoxNzAyNzU5NzUyfQ.Oz7iBmkfPCVDr0s-JlzGjyvpZIPvJBYsrjqOT0tJQ3w";

let splittedByDot = raw.split(".");

let output = [];

for (let item of splittedByDot) {
    if (item.indexOf("-") === -1) {
        output.push(JSON.parse(atob(item)));
    } else {
        output.push(item.split("-").map(i => atob(i)).join("-"));
    }
}

console.log(output);
```

Comment: It didn't work, because the `atob()` doesn't work in my environment for some reason, anyway I already got an answer that solved my problem. Thank you for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

STEP 1
Install npm install core-js

STEP 2
import "core-js/stable/atob";

Now simply use
const token = "your_token";

const decoded = jwtDecode(token);